# How to get Header info or Footer info from XLSX File with Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, excel, typescript, xlsx

[HEADER XLSX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vu6mL.png)

I have only found how to access the information within the xlsx book but I need the header / footer

I already tried this way.

```
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

const firstSheetName = ws.SheetNames[0];
const worksheet = ws.Sheets[firstSheetName];

const headerCells = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, { header: 1 })[0];

console.log("headerCells :",headerCells);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to read headers and footers with XLSX (`headerFooter` tag in `sheet.xml`).

Try with [ExcelJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs):

```
worksheet.headerFooter.oddFooter
```

docs:

[Headers and Footers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs#headers-and-footers)